# Question regarding finding a basis vector

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Let's say we have a set of coordinates in spherical co-ordinate system ,the coordinates are (r,θ,φ). To change the Spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordiantes we write it as

$$x=r\sin θ \sin φ, y=\sin θ \cos φ, z=r \cos θ$$

the position vector is given by ,

$$\vec ρ=r \sin θ \sin φ \vec i+r \sin θ \cos φ \vec j+r \cos θ \vec k$$

now to get the basis vector say $\vec θ$ we divide the derivative of position vector with respect to θ and the magnitude of the position vector with respect to $θ$,

that is

$$\vec θ =\frac{\frac{\partial \vec ρ}{\partial θ}} {\left|\frac{\partial \vec ρ}{\partial θ}\right|}$$

but why does a derivative divided by its magnitude give us the basis vector?

Answer (score 0):

By definition multiplication of a vector by a scalar modify the “length” of the vector but not its direction that is

$$ \vec v=| \vec v|\frac{\vec v}{| \vec v|}$$

with $\frac{\vec v}{| \vec v|}$ unitary direction vector for $\vec v$.

Let try with some numerical example as $\vec v=(1,2,3)$.

Refer also to the related

- [Vector multiplication with scalars](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24038/505767)

Comment: I understand how we find the unit vector ,but how does dividing a partial derivative by its magnitude give us a unit vector

Comment: $\rho$ is a vector and also its derivative is a vector.